ReorderableListView doesn't provide the option to drag the items
In my app, the user can add how many items they desire. If they want to reorder it they can simply open the general dialog and use a ReorderableListView.
However, when the dialog is shown, the ReorderableListView doesn't provide the option to drag items to reorder them.
Here is the method that shows the dialog:
Future<Object?> reorderDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return showGeneralDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierLabel: "Barrier",
      barrierDismissible: true,
      barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
      transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) {
        return SizedBox.expand(
            child: Dialog(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 300,
            child: ReorderableListView(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              children: widget.workout.exerciseList
                  .map(
                    (exercise) => Card(
                      key: ValueKey(exercise.id!),
                      child: ListTile(
                        tileColor:
                            widget.workout.exerciseList.indexOf(exercise).isOdd
                                ? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary
                                : Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                        title: Text('${exercise.exercise.title}'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                  .toList(),
              onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
                setState(() {
                  if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
                    newIndex -= 1;
                  }
                  final item = widget.workout.exerciseList.removeAt(oldIndex);
                  widget.workout.exerciseList.insert(newIndex, item);
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ));
      },
      transitionBuilder: (_, anim, __, child) {
        Tween<Offset> tween;
        if (anim.status == AnimationStatus.reverse) {
          tween = Tween(begin: Offset(-1, 0), end: Offset.zero);
        } else {
          tween = Tween(begin: Offset(1, 0), end: Offset.zero);
        }

        return SlideTransition(
          position: tween.animate(anim),
          child: FadeTransition(
            opacity: anim,
            child: child,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

I can also provide an image of what is shown:

I don't know what's missing, so if you can give me any sort of advice it would be very helpful. Thanks.
